# Creating an island for separate gravity control on XNA using Farseer Physics Engine 3.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, farseer

I just started using the Farseer engine and so far it's been pretty easy to understand and implement in my aps. I was wondering if there was a way to put a control into a different "world" so that I can manipulate the gravity of just that object but allow other objects to stay at the default world gravity. Does anyone know how to accomplish this or know of any resources that might help me?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to change gravity for specific objects is a bit unusual, as gravity normally is a global constant in a physics simulation (unless you are using space stuff).
I don't know Farseer engine but I assume gravity works the same as in other physics engines.

Usually in physics to manipulate just one object's 'gravity' you simply lower it's weight/mass (and air friction?). Or even give it a slight upward force (a negative to gravity).

Comment: Well supposedly there is a way to isolate an item to it's own gravity. An example use would be accelerometer game use where you want to move an single object using gravity so that other moving objects are not effected by it. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Then why don't you remove gravity and give each object a downwards force manually? Force = mass * Gravity, do that for all your objects, and you can manage gravity for all objects.
I's not really going to increase your CPU time on physics update by much.

...Or there is an easy way to do it with Farseer xD